# How do I mock an AbstractValidator that is using rule sets?

Tags: c#, moq, fluentvalidation

I have an abstract validator, with the following structure:

```
public abstract class RiskAssessmentServiceCreateRequestValidator<T>
    : AbstractValidator<T> where T
        : IRiskAssessmentServiceCreateRequest
{
    public RiskAssessmentServiceCreateRequestValidator(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        RuleSet("modelBinding", () =>
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.ServiceProviderId).NotNull().GreaterThan(0);
        });

        RuleSet("handler", () =>
        {
            //....
        });

    }
}
```

In my request handler I am calling a derived instance of this class like that:

```
var validationResult = _validator.Validate(request, ruleSet: "handler");
```

How can I mock that particular call to Validate in my unit tests? If I would not use the rule sets, my Setup would look like this:

```
_validator.Setup(x => x.Validate(It.IsAny<CreateRequest>()))
          .Returns(validationResult);
```

The following call is not allowed, since optional parameters are not allowed in an expression tree:

```
_validator.Setup(x => x.Validate(
                It.IsAny<CreateRequest>(), 
                ruleSet: It.IsAny<string>()))
          .Returns(validationResult);
```

Theoretically I could set it up like this:

```
_validator.Setup(x => x.Validate(
                It.IsAny<CreateRequest>(), 
                (IValidatorSelector)null,
                It.IsAny<string>()))
           .Returns(validationResult);
```

But this then results in:

```
System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x.Validate<CreateRequest>(It.IsAny<CreateRequest>(), null, It.IsAny<string>())
    Extension methods (here: DefaultValidatorExtensions.Validate) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
```

Except from using the real validator, which I want to avoid, how can I resolve this and setup Moq in a suitable way?

Comment: Treat optional parameters as not-optional when mocking. However, it looks like that method is an extension method so you cannot mock it. Instead, you still mock the actual underlying method that the extension calls.

Comment: For example, it looks like under the hood it is calling [`validator.Validate(ValidationContext)`](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/blob/master/src/FluentValidation/IValidator.cs#L78) but that's a guess.

Comment: @DavidG good guess https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/blob/master/src/FluentValidation/AbstractValidator.cs#L70

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are really two questions here.

1. The first is how to mock with optional parameters - Simply treat optional parameters are non-optional.
2. However, you are trying to mock an extension method, that is not possible. Instead, you need to mock the method that the extension is trying to call. A cursory glance at the source, and I think that under the hood it is calling [`validator.Validate(ValidationContext)`](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/blob/master/src/FluentValidation/IValidator.cs#L78) so your Moq code could be something like this:

   ```
   _validator
       .Setup(x => x.Validate(It.IsAny<ValidationContext<CreateRequest>>())
       .Returns(validationResult);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var mock = new Mock<AbstractValidator<object>>();
mock.Setup(x => x.Validate(It.Is<ValidationContext<object>>(ctx => IsExpectedRuleSet(ctx, new[] { "Rule1", "Rule2" }))))
    .Return(...);

mock.Object.Validate(new object(), ruleSet: "Rule1,Rule2");

bool IsExpectedRuleSet(ValidationContext context, string[] expectedRuleSet)
{
    return (context.Selector as FluentValidation.Internal.RulesetValidatorSelector)?.RuleSets.SequenceEqual(expectedRuleSet) == true;
}
```